# Зачем в данном контексте ключевое слово new?

Tags: c++, ооп

Имеется вот такой код. Зачем тут ключевое слово new? Почему не дает использовать укзатель * на объект NOTE?

```
{
    if (head == nullptr)
    {
        head = new Node(data);
    }
    else {
        Node* temp = this->head;
        while (temp->next != nullptr)
        {
            temp= temp->next;
        }
        temp->next = new Node(data);
    }
    Size++;
}
```

Comment: new делает новый объект класса Node. И как Вы хотите использовать указатель на **NOTE** ?

Comment: @KoVadim разобрался, но new выделяет память, и в то же время делает новый объект.

Comment: new выделяет память под объект и вызывает подходящий конструктор. Да, с помощью new можно создать массив целых чисел, но почему бы и нет